# Testing-related methodologies except TDD/BDD

Tags: testing, tdd, bdd

Are there any testing-related methodologies except TDD/BDD? I see a lot of people who practice their own testing approaches (e. g., see Ayende [post](http://ayende.com/blog/4217/even-tests-has-got-to-justify-themselves)), but I don't see any formalization for it, no naming for these approaches.

Comment: It may sound odd to you, but TDD/BDD are not really testing methodologies. TDD is a coding methodolgy producing just (and only) white-box unit tests, no other form of tests. BDD is a design methodology.

Comment: @Doc Brown, yep, I know this "TDD is about design" thing. I have fixed the title. Is it okay now?

Comment: the title of your question is ok. But I suspect if you ask for testing methodologies in this very broad way, you will just get a list of buzz-words. Sure that this is what you want?

Comment: @Doc Brown, the problem is I actually can't remind any buzzword which will fit the question. So at this stage even just buzzwords will satisfy me.

Comment: well, if you just want an introduction into testing terms, why not just have a look into Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing

Comment: @Doc Brown, I want to get examples of testing methodologies which solve problem which TDD/BDD solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most test methodologies are integral to the development process they support.  For example, in the Waterfall Model, testing follows as feasibility, requirements analysis, system design conformity, Code/Unit testing, Integration/System Testing and finally deployment review/refactoring.  It's arguable that this would be called the "Waterfall test" methodology but in effect, that's what it is.

In agile testing, more emphasis is placed on test automation, paired programming (instant test feedback!) and QA within the iterative build cycle.

There are very well defined test methods depending on the software life-cycle needs.  Exhaustive lists are available elsewhere but the more common methods include, unit, integration, stress, performance and system testing.

Unlike development processes, however, rigorously defined test methodologies as a standalone practice is lacking.  Instead, QA standards are set by a variety of bodies including ISO and CMMi.

Answer (score 1):

Testing is a very general term covering a **huge field**, so there are a lot of methodologies involved, e.g. risk-based testing, model-based testing or random testing.

It actually makes sense to build a **taxonomie**, differentiating e.g. manual vs automated testing, white-box vs. black-box testing and the level in the [V model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model) (unit, component, system). [Here is a mindmap that gives a rough taxonomie.](http://gogeometry.com/software/software_testing_mind_map_9.gif)

If you come across a technical term, you will probably find it in [this glossary from **ISTQB**, which is by far the best I know of](http://istqb.org/download/attachments/2326555/ISTQB+Glossary+of+Testing+Terms+2+1.pdf). ISTQB also offers several syllabus in which you can read up what the terms mean. [This foundational syllabus](http://istqb.org/download/attachments/2326555/Foundation+Level+Syllabus+%282007%29.pdf) is a good start.